# C++ MongoDB how to "lock" collection so other processes can't write it

Tags: c++, mongodb, locking

I'm writing an app and it would run on multiple servers.

Let's say I have 2 collections `X` and `Y`.

`X` has documents like this: `{ _id : 123, name : "something"}`

`Y` has documents like this: `{ _id : 456, parent_id : 123, name : "anything"}`

When I delete a document from `X` I want to delete all children from `Y` and also I want to somehow lock collection `Y` so *server n* can't write any new document to `Y` with that exact  parent_id.

What I understood MongoDB has no collection level locks, so how exactly should I solve this problem?

Also keep in mind that merging the two collections into one is not an option for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB locks are not the problem here since MongoDB actually locks on database level which meant that if you could effect more than one collection with a single query then this would be easily possible, however, as it stands that is not easily possible without using `eval`ed JavaScript; this I would not do for multiple reasons:- one being that all queries that touch `x` and/or `y` would need to be in JS for the global JS lock to have the effect needed.

The only real way I can think of solving this in a decent manner would be to apply some sort of `lock` collection which other queries must query against first, or you could add a `locked` field to the document in the collection and use an atomic operation to set it so that no other queries can touch those `locked` documents. This would be required since, due to concurrency features, MongoDB can actually subside non-atomic operations when data is not paged in for other operations.

Those two methods are currently the best I can come up with.